# set destination page in url

Tags: php, html, url

I have a form. when the user clicks a link on the form , I want to redirect him to the login page and once he logs in , he should be directed back to the form page and not any other page.

How do i achieve this redirection. Is there a way by setting the destination of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 scripts :

Script A with the login form :

```
    <form id="someId" action="login-action.php?redirect=<?php print(urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
```

In your script B, you check the redirect key in the GET array. If the key exists, you use it to redirect the script :

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['redirect'])){

    header('location:'.urldecode($_GET['redirect']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header();` to redirect the browser. Here's a quick scenario:

```
<?php

if (md5($_POST['password']) == $server_password) // You are hashing, right ;)
{
  header('location:www.example.com');
}

?>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that redirects to the login page, take the current request URL (with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), urlencode it (using the appropriately named urlencode function), and append it to the URL you redirect to as a query string variable (say something like returnurl).

Then, in the login page, check to see if returnurl is in the query string, and redirect to it if it is.

I don't know PHP too well, but this should get you in the right direction.